# Neo4j - creating relationships for referential integrity

Tags: csv, neo4j, cypher

I have ingested all the tables and columns metadata, now i'm trying to create relationships using referential integrity. I have a csv file with 6 columns namely table_schema, table_name, col_name ,referenced_table_schema, referenced_table_name and referenced_column_name. Now i just need to create a relationship between the existing column nodes that are available. The cypher query that I tried

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///column_ref_integrity.csv" AS csv
 MATCH (n:column), (m:table), (o:db)
 where n.col_name=csv.col_name and m.table_name =csv.table_name and o.db_name = csv.table_schema
where n.col_name=csv.referenced_column_name and m.table_name = csv.referenced_table_name and o.db_name=referenced.db_name
 MERGE  (n{col_name:csv.col_name})-[:refers]->(n{col_name:csv.referenced_column_name})
```

This query doesn't seem to work. Any pointers about what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What is the error you are getting? There are 2 consecutive WHERE clause in your query which is not supported.

Comment: Removed the consecutive where clauses as well and tried the same. It is creating new nodes with relationships between both and not using the existing ones. And when I tried different versions of it, It is not creating any relationship at all. I'm just wondering, typically how would it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may work for you:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///column_ref_integrity.csv" AS row
MATCH (c1:column), (c2:column)
WHERE c1.col_name = row.col_name AND c2.col_name = row.referenced_column_name
MERGE (c1)-[:refers]->(c2) 
WITH row
MATCH (t1:table), (t2:table)
WHERE t1.table_name = row.table_name AND t2.table_name = row.referenced_table_name
MERGE (t1)-[:refers]->(t2) 
WITH row
MATCH (d1:db), (d2:db)
WHERE d1.db_name = row.table_schema AND d2.db_name = row.referenced_table_schema
MERGE (d1)-[:refers]->(d2)
```

Comment: ```LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///column_ref_integrity.csv" AS row
MATCH (c1:column), (c2:column), (t1:table), (t2:table), (d1:db), (d2:db)
WHERE c1.col_name = row.col_name AND c2.col_name = row.referenced_column_name AND t1.table_name = row.table_name AND t2.table_name = row.referenced_table_name AND 
d1.db_name = row.table_schema AND d2.db_name = row.referenced_table_schema
MERGE (c1)-[:refers]->(c2) 
```
I modified the query a bit to fit my case. Although it creates the relationship, it is creating two relationships referencing each other.

Comment: Instead of column->referenced_column alone, yet another relationship with referenced_column->column is also created

Comment: Your CSV file probably has 2 rows that cause that. The Cypher code is very simple and would not cause bidirectional relationships on its own. (Also, if you only care about `column` nodes, why do you bother getting `table` and `db` nodes at all? Something like the first 4 lines of my answer would be all you needed in that case.)

Comment: Only column match tends to create relationships with other columns from different schemas, so had to match db_name, table_name and column_name for creating a unique relationship and the csv file has only two rows with two unique column matches. So wrapping my head around that a bit

Comment: The above query still tends to create relationships with column names from different tables but same schema. Any idea what's wrong with that query?